# How to predict the next data of Stock in Machine Learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I have tried a basic prediction with the existing data. [Screenshot attached]

How can I make a next predicted data i.e (n+1)

**For Example:**

I have 1000 records and I want the predicted result of 1001th record.

Also confusion matrix is not working for Regression Model. Please tell me that also.

Please reply and give me a solution.

Thank You
[image]
[image]

Comment: Confusion matrix is only applicable in classification problems, not in regression ones

Answer (score 0):

> There are multiple ways of doing this, and as of now your question is posed too broad to be answered in a detailed way.

- you could train a recurrent neural network
- you could do a simple Regression to predict the next Point in your series

Depending on your preferences try to do some Research on "time series prediction" and you'll find a lot of Information on how to get started.

Also as you noticed a confusion Matrix is not working for a Regression model. You Need to come up with another metric instead (e.g. mean square error, signed mean square error, anything else that suits your purpose to evaluate the Performance of your predictor)